# Var assigned in Blazor component are linked with the main var

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

Var assigned in Blazor component is linked with the main var.

A ASP.NET Core hosted project of Blazor in the client project I have a component with some inputText. I use as Model a 'Person' class and I'm assigning Person2 from Person on OnInitializedAsync() , 
When the model (Person) is modified via inputText, Person is modified simultaneously, and I don't know why.
This process is because I want to keep the Person state before the user modifies it and be able to go back to the previous state if the user clicks button 'Cancel'.
How can I do it?
Thank you

Mi component:

```
<EditForm Model="Person" OnValidSubmit="SendPerson" class="form-inline col-11">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div class="m-auto">
        <InputText class="" @bind-Value="@Person.Nom" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Person.Nom)" />
    </div>

    <div class="m-auto">
        <InputText class="" @bind-Value="@Person.Cognom1" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Person.Cognom1)" />
    </div>

    <div class="m-auto">
        <InputDate class="" @bind-Value="@Person.Cognom2" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Person.Cognom2)" />
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary m-auto" type="submit">Send</button>

</EditForm>
<button class="btn btn-warning col-1 m-auto" @onclick="CancelPerson"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Cancel</button>

@code {
[Parameter]
public persones Person { get; set; }

public persones Person2 { get; set; }

async Task SendPerson()
{
    var result = await Http.PostJsonAsync<persones>("api/Persones/SetPerson", Person);
}

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    base.OnInitialized();
    Person2 = Person;
}

private void CancelPerson()
{
    Person = Person2;
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because both variables contain the same object and point to the same location in the memory (reference types). But forget this...
You should instead store your object in the local storage immediately before it is made available for use. If need aroused, as for instance, your user presses a cancel button, you can read this value from the local storage. This is why we have local storage. It is much used when you create a wizard components, cart components, and such like. It can be used by both Blazor Server Apps and Blazor WebAssembly Apps. You can use JSInterop to call the JavaScript localStorage and sessionStorage directly, or, preferably use Blazor libraries created by the community or by the Blazor team.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think about it!! I use localStorage for storing other things, and I can also use it for that

Answer (score 1):

When you assigning a reference type ([value-vs-reference-typ](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)) to another variable, you are basically storing a reference (pointer) to the object and you are not making a copy of this object. When you make a change to persones object that is referenced from Person variable, then Person2 variable, which has the same reference, changes as well.

I believe there has to be some instantiation of persones class, because in OnInitialized() you assigning null to null if it is class and EditForm would have complain about null 'things'.

Comment: You are right about the reference type assignation, What I am assigning is a class.
I think I will have to map all properties one by one, which is what I wanted to avoid, I don't know how I could do it.
About 'assigning null to null' Person1 is not null because is a parameter, for this reason the EditForm doesn't complain.